# how to establish a connection between an arduino and a web server?

Tags: arduino-mega, web-server, ethernet-shield

I want to establish a connection between my arduino mega ( which is connected to an ethernet shield so internet access is available) to a web server. Any idea how the code should be? 
I searched for it but all I found was a local host connection establishment.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of the examples in the IDE help you?

Comment: That's the one thing i forgot to check. I'll get to it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of this was already existing in the arduino examples which I forgot to check at first. Thanks Majenko for making me notice.

Comment: @jsotola - actually this is an answer, as it resolves the question.  When a solution is posted as a comment, summarizing it in an answer is permitted; short of closing the question (as subsequently happened here) it's typically the only way the system can be convinced to consider the issue resolved and avoid having it bubble back up every few months to annoy everyone.